# How to find address that are shorthand or standard version? N or North, NW or NorthWest

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex, database

Court or CT
Lane or LN
Boulevard or BLVD, etc

Is there a api that will sanitize a database into shorthand, or someway to clean a database so that when I do a search query I can find the address?

Currently I do:

```
WHERE prod.street_num = new.street_num AND prod.street_name LIKE (CONCAT('%',new.street_name,'%'))
```

Comment: Could you include an example of some data in your database and an example of what you're trying to achieve? I don't fully understand what you need help with

Comment: address in database could be
123 Main St
Address that I am comparing to see if it is the same could be
123 Main Street

Comment: For data like that, you need to process it before inserting into the database.  The processing should cleanse the data of abbreviations, alternate spellings, optional hyphenation, etc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think changing your query to something like this can achieve what you want.

```
AND MATCH(prod.street_name) AGAINST (new.street_name IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE);
```

I have tried it online, which you can check out [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0275/3), and it seems to be working with the functionality you want.
You can also check the documentation on Full Text Search in MySQL [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

(Note: I am mostly a Postgres user but I hope this helps!)